# Is "of" strictly needed in "out 'of' the [door]/[city]"?

Tags: prepositions

> A1. I stuck my head **out the** door just to check that the place wasn't burning down.
>
> A2. I stuck my head **out of  the** door just to check that the place wasn't burning down.
>
> B1. There may be some changes in migration, but people really like to seek **out the** city as a destination to live.
>
> B2. There may be some changes in migration, but people really like to seek **out of the** city as a destination to live.

Can anybody explain if "of" is mandatory just after "out" in sentences like ones above? If not, is there a rule governing this kind of "of" usage?

Answer (score 3):

In A1 and A2, *of* is optional. In Standard English you can say *I stuck my head out the door*, or *I stuck my head out of the door*.

B uses the phrasal verb *[seek out](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/seek+out#seek__23)*.  B1 is grammatical, but in B2, *seek out of the city* is ungrammatical. (This is because you cannot add *of* in between *seek out* and the thing the people are seeking out. You could write *seek the city out*.) So, since it is mandatory *not* to use *of* in B, B may not be the easiest example to compare to A. Let's try a different set:

> C1. I got some sunshine earlier, when I went out the house to get groceries.
>
> C2. I got some sunshine earlier, when I went out of the house to get groceries.

C1 is ungrammatical in Standard English. When we talk about going out of the house, *of* is required.

The difference may be that *of* is optional for looking or going through small openings, but required for big things and containers. If you are in doubt, use *of*.

A [Language Log entry](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3167) has more to say:

> You can walk — or run, crawl, scurry, roll, etc. — out the gate, out the back, out the exit, etc. You can look — or stare, peer, gaze, squint, etc. — out the window, out the porthole, out the viewport, out the sunroof, etc.
>
> But you can't (standardly) walk out the house, or out the plaza, or out the village, or whatever — all of those need "of". Nor can you (standardly) peer out the box, or stare out the car, or shoot out the bushes — though you can perfectly well shoot at someone out of the bushes, etc.

Comment: In your list beginning with *walk*, you include *roll*.  *Roll out* can also be a phrasal verb, as in *roll out the red carpet*, and in that case, *of* is distinctly unwanted.  (*Roll out the barrel* is something entirely different; it's possible to *roll out of a barrel* if by some mischance you got into one, but it's not at all the same thing as the expression without *of*.)  Also, with those verbs, I'd usually use *through* if I felt a preposition was needed after *out*.

Comment: About two screens down from the top, the [Language Log entry that you cited](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3167) says, “Apparently _out_ as a transitive preposition has something to do with transiting from within an enclosed space through a limited aperture of some kind.”  I.e., you can move _out_ an opening or portal (like a door), but you must move _out of_ a container (like a house or a city).  Putting it another way: If ***out through*** makes sense, then you can probably say ***out***.  If ***out through*** doesn’t make sense, then you probably should say ***out of***.

Answer (score 2):

In US use, at least, *of* is not required in the 'A' sentences. *Out*, *out of* and *outside*  will all work.

In the 'B' sentences, however, *seek out* (likewise *search out*) is a distinct idiom; it's roughly equivalent to *seek* by itself, but it implies the search is carried out among a group or population:

> He sought out the most respected authority he could identify.

Accordingly, you really need *out of* rather than simply *out* here; and *outside* would be even better, since the *out* in *out of* will give the reader momentary pause.

Further, in informal use you are far more likely to encounter *look* than *seek*. *Seek* has a literary ring today.

Comment: Indeed, *Look out!* is a rather common warning; its impact is usually conveyed by intonation.  If it's extended to anything more specific, then it would be *look out for ...*

Comment: @barbarabeeton Very good point. I may have to rewrite this altogether.