# Is the expression "He ran out the door" idiomatic?

Tags: idiomatic-language

If one says "he ran out" it's perfectly understandable but to run out the door to my non native brain sounds a bit idiomatic, am I right?

Comment: This feels like a duplicate of the [question asking about "I puke out the window"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/245823/41273), and in fact you're quoting the same sentence from Lexico that's in my answer. Does that answer your question?

Comment: You can find [many, many examples of "he ran out the door" at Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+ran+out+the+door%22).

Comment: Related: [Is "of" strictly needed in "out of the door/city"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/1382/9161)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The expression "He ran out the door" is literal, even though "He ran out of the room" is more accurate.

"Out" is simply being used as a casual form of "out of".

"Door" is often used to include the opening or frame where the door is located. i.e. the doorway.

He was in the room. He went to the door. He opened the door, and ran through the doorway to the outside.

"He ran out the door." is a simplified, casual version of the above, but it's not an idiom.

Comment: Welcome to ELL. "Idiomatic" means a sentence or phrase sounds natural and would be used by native speakers.